# How to edit Full Calendar back forward buttons UI

Tags: angular

I am using Full alendar in angular2 code please sugest me how to change the style of Back forward button UI.
https://fullcalendar.io

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the classes in your own .css file. Just check in some inspect tool the classes for Buttons and overwrite theirs properties.

If you want to change the icons, check : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/buttonIcons/

buttonIcons property object:

```
{
    prev: 'left-single-arrow',
    next: 'right-single-arrow',
    prevYear: 'left-double-arrow',
    nextYear: 'right-double-arrow'
}
```

Comment: how to impliment using type script, i have impliment this full calender in Angular2 code.

Comment: I am not sure it's implemented in PrimeNG (is buttonIcons forwarded to fullcalendar.io instance). But if isn't you can try to force some CSS styles on fullcalendar